# Why I can't install the pygraphviz package in Python?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, anaconda, pygraphviz

I used Anaconda3 to install pygraphviz package. First time, the error occurred which said the Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required, so I installed the Visual Studio Community 2015(in the programming language the C++ module is also installed). However, the following error appeared:

```
  Collecting pygraphviz
  Using cached pygraphviz-1.3.1.zip
  Building wheels for collected packages: pygraphviz
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pygraphviz ... error
  Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\zd1n14\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-pao661qp\\pygraphviz\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\zd1n14\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp29u6yzrxpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz\agraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz\graphviz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_attribute_defaults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_clear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_drawing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_edge_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_graph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_html.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_layout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_node_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_readwrite.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_string.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_subgraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  copying pygraphviz\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz\tests
  running egg_info
  writing pygraphviz.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info\top_level.txt
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found`

  reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
  writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying pygraphviz\graphviz.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygraphviz
  running build_ext
  building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pygraphviz
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /Tcpygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.obj
  graphviz_wrap.c
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2954): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you're missing `graphviz/cgraph.h`. Solution - Install Graphviz. Duh

Comment: Thanks, I have already installed Graphviz.

Comment: Why are you trying to build this yourself? Why not `conda install pygraphviz`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But the following statements shown: 
                                                                                                       
`Fetching package metadata`
`PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - pygraphviz`

`Close matches found; did you mean one of these?`

`pygraphviz: graphviz, python-graphviz, pyqtgraph`

Comment: Hi! @zdeng Did u get solution for this???

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the solution.